# Override django admin landing page and pass variables to template

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am new to use python and django.
I want to override django admin landing page. So i am able to do this with creating template base_site.html and index.html in templates/admin/ folder.

Now, i am able to display static content on /admin (django admin landing) page in index.html.
I searched a lot but not getting, how can i pass the parameters or variables to index.html file.

Comment: What variables do you want to pass to index.html?

Comment: I want to show statistic for reporting part so there i need to fetch data from table and display it on admin page, where i am going to display count and all the thing

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to write a custom template tag that will fetch data from the db and render the output however you want it.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags

Potential drawbacks are that the database query will be run every single time your Django-admin index page is requested.

A better way would be to create a view that returns the data you need to display as JSON.

Your view will look something like this, where you get your stats from `MyModel`.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json

def get_statisics(request):
    j = MyModel.objects.values('field_a', 'field_b')
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(j), content_type='application/json')
```

You will need to add a placeholder `div` or any HTML element in the overridden template and write some JavaScript that fetches data from your view (via AJAX) and adds it to the template.

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/stats/',  // url to the `get_statistics` view
      dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(data) {
      // read `data` and put it in your template
      $('#placeholder-div').text(data);
    });
  });
}(django.jQuery));
```

The above example will just show your JSON in the placeholder element as is, but you can do whatever you want with the data. Render a table / chart / graph.

You can then cache the `get_statistics` view to avoid running a database query every time an AJAX call is made to it.